# Using CardLayout in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, cardlayout

```
getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout());
CardLayout x = (CardLayout) getLayout();
```

I'm using Netbeans and in Design manager I chosed my JFrame contents as CardLayout. However I cannot make it work so far. I set the above code after the initComponenets call and still I have this error:

```
java.awt.BorderLayout cannot be cast to java.awt.CardLayout
```

Somehow I have BorderLayout instead of CardLayout. How is it possible? I've just set layout as CardLayout. PS: my class extends javax.swing.JFrame.

Comment: 1) I typically find it easier and cleaner to either add a single `JPanel` to the content pane, or set it ***as*** the content pane.  Then anything to do with borders, layout, color can be done to the `JPanel`. 2) *"my class extends `javax.swing.JFrame`"*  Don't extend frame unless adding or overriding methods.  Just keep a reference to one.

Comment: I'm a netbeans and java newby so I don't really know about borders and stuff. I used netbeans generated code from Swing GUI Forms>Application Sample Form. Then added 2 panels and CardLayout Layout. When I try to switch, I get these errors. I'd appreciate if there is any easier way to get around this.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665156/calling-awt-frame-methods-from-subclass/5786005#5786005) for a working `CardLayout`.  I think you should put Netbeans to the side for the moment and learn how to code Java.

Comment: I know if I code JPanel and frame by hand, it works. I've just swtiched to Netbeans from Eclipse because it has native GUI manager and spent a lot of hours to switch from SWT to Swing. Unfortunately I don't have time to write write GUI by code since I have to focus on back-end of the project. I just need a quick fix for Netbenas that I can continue coding the backend.

Comment: *"I just need a quick fix for Netbenas"*  Hire someone.  Voting to close as 'too localized'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, no you got me wrong. I'm searching for a fix that I use it in Netbeans. I already search web for hours. This is the last place for me to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
CardLayout x = (CardLayout) getContentPane().getLayout();
```

Similarly to switch card panels you can use:

```
x.show(getContentPane(), "card2");
```

This is *not* an issue if you simply use a separate `JPanel` as the 'card' container plus you get the added benefit of using the `JFrame` `BorderLayout` should you wish to add navigation buttons, say in the `BorderLayout.SOUTH` location.

[Essential reading for using CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! Then I get this error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong parent for CardLayout`. I've just tried that with brand new project.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using the wrong container for `CardLayout.show`

Comment: I've been tring to do it by "next" and I gave layout's name as the arguement. It seemed like code failed at assignment, not at "next" statement. show with string name worked. BTW: I read this page as well but apparently I didn't paid enough attention. Thanks a lot!